# Pattern to evaluate <img src=x onerror=alert(1)>

Tags: regex

I need a pattern to evaluate the above tag. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Use an HTML parser.

Comment: sorry but i need regex only

Comment: Have you tried Googling for this, or searching Stack Overflow?

Comment: Yeah tried but no pattern matched my search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regexp should work:

```
<img src=[^>]* onerror=alert\(1\)>
```

You need to escape `(` and `)` because they have special meaning in regular expressions. `[^>]*` matches any string that doesn't include `>`, so it won't go across different `img` tags.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me but i used it as <img src=[^>]* >

Comment: I thought you were specifically looking for images with this `onerror` attribute.